# How to make Firefox address bar favor bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

When you type something in the address bar, Firefox searches a bunch of things, including browsing history, bookmarks, open tabs, etc. How do I tell Firefox to favor bookmarks so I can find them quickly? Sometimes Firefox shows a lot of entries from my browsing history and none of my bookmarks.

Comment: This is probably better on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox).

Comment: @thirtydot thank you. I didn't know about `Super User` before.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to improve the priority of your bookmark, you can go to `about:preferences#search` page and in **Default Search Engine** uncheck `Show search suggestions ahead of browsing history in address bar results` or uncheck `Provide search suggestions`.

Firefox takes into account how frequently and how recently sites in the browser history and bookmarks were visited, combining them into an algorithm called [frecency algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Frecency_algorithm).

You could adjust (increase) the value of the [places.frecency.*BucketWeight](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.frecency.%2ABucketWeight) preferences though to boost the ranking of more recent visits and adjust the timespan in days for the different buckets through [places.frecency.*BucketCutoff](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.frecency.%2ABucketCutoff). You could also adjust the "weight" it gives to certain types of URLs—like bookmarks through [places.frecency.*VisitBonus](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.frecency.%28visit_type%29VisitBonus).

In your case, if you want to increase the priority of bookmarks, I think you can increase the value of `places.frecency.unvisitedBookmarkBonus`, so those unvisited bookmarks can get more scores then rank higher. You could also give more bonus to visited bookmarks by increasing the value of `places.frecency.bookmarkVisitBonus`.

Moreover, you can change the number of suggestions in the address bar dropdown
by changing the value of `browser.urlbar.maxRichResults` in `about:config`.

---

At least in the version of 89.0, firefox now supports `Bookmarks` search engines. You can search only bookmarks by clicking the icon or typing `*` (You can customize this in `about:preferences#search` **Search Shortcuts** section) before your search keywords.

[image]

There will be a `Bookmarks` keyword at the front of search bar if you use the bookmark search engine.

[image]

Comment: Those settings relate only to *search suggestions* (by Google etc) and *browsing history* — and seem to have nothing to do with *bookmarks*.

Comment: I did a quick test and changing frecency bonus of the mentioned bookmark config entries made no difference whatsoever. The bookmark suggestions stayed buried in the middle of the suggestions list.

Comment: TIL frecency is "any heuristic that combines the frequency and recency into a single measure"

Comment: The same question on the mozilla support site, with good answers: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1220406

Answer (score 5):

You can type `special characters` after search term to tell Firefox to favor certain things. For example, you can type `*` after a term to tell Firefox to search only bookmarks. Fore more info, see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/address-bar-autocomplete-firefox#w_changing-results-on-the-fly

Comment: `*` can be typed before one or more search terms too: `*linux driver` gives the same as `linux driver*`.

Comment: By the way: what other special characters can we use?

Comment: @cipricus the linked article has a list :)